# How Can I Add users to roles with IdentityCore?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I have an Admin controller which I manage both users and roles. I have EditRole IAction method which works good. The scenario is when I go to that view, I see lets say Admin role and the users with that role.[image: EditRole]

When I go to Add | Remove users I see the user added to the role. I want to add other users to that role.
Here is what I tried:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditUsersInRole(string roleId//This comes from EditRole action)
    {

        ViewBag.RoleID = roleId;

        var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);

        if (role == null)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"{roleId} this id was not found.";
            return View("NotFound");
        }

        //I have created ViewModel to keep user details
    
        var model = new List<UserRoleViewModel>();

        using (DALC.GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select*from AspNetUsers u join AspNetUserRoles r on u.Id = r.UserId", DALC.con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Id = dr["Id"].ToString(),
                    UserName = dr["UserName"].ToString()
                };
                var userRole = new UserRoleViewModel();
                if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                {
                    userRole.UserId = user.Id;
                    userRole.UserName = user.UserName;
                    userRole.IsSelected = true;
                }
                model.Add(userRole);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

**The result**: I want to type a username and add it to the role.
[image]

**And The Post method:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditUsersInRole(List<UserRoleViewModel> model, string roleId)
    {
        var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
        if (role == null)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"{roleId} tapilmadi";
            return View("NotFound");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < model.Count(); i++)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(model[i].UserId);

            IdentityResult result = null;
            
            if (model[i].IsSelected && !(await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name)))
            {
                result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
            }
            else if (!model[i].IsSelected && await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
            {
                result = await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (i < (model.Count - 1))
                    continue;
                else
                    return RedirectToAction("EditRole", new { Id = roleId });
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("EditRole", new { Id = roleId });
    }
```

**strong text**

Comment: Do you meet any error or exception? According to your code, you are using UserManager and RoleManager to manage the user and role, to add the specified user to the role, you are using the userManager.AddToRoleAsync() method, it is correct. So, could you explain more detail about the issue? You could also try to set a break point in your code and step by step to debug the code.

Comment: @ZhiLv sure, when I want to add users to specific selected role. so I did it myself but I can add one record.. what I wanted to add multiple users to that role.